# For subspaces $Y, W$ show that $Y \subset W$ iff for the symplectic complements $W^{\Omega} \subset Y^{\Omega}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

The question is already in the title.
Say we have a vector space $V$ and subspaces $Y,W$. Show that
$Y \subset W \Leftrightarrow W^{\Omega} \subset Y^{\Omega}$
where by $\Omega$ I mean the simplectic orthogonal.
The direction $\Rightarrow$ is no problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just apply the first implication with $W^\Omega$ and $Y^\Omega$ playing the roles of $Y$ and $W$, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with an answer myself.
For the direction $"\Leftarrow"$
we know that $W = (W^{\Omega})^{\Omega}$ and $Y = (Y^{\Omega})^{\Omega}$.
But under the assumption: $W^{\Omega} \subset Y^{\Omega}$, we know that every $\tilde{w} \in (Y^{\Omega})^{\Omega}$ has the property that $\omega(\tilde{w},Y^{\Omega}) = 0$. But then it must hold that $\omega(\tilde{w},W^{\Omega}) = 0$ and therefore $\tilde{w} \in (W^{\Omega})^{\Omega}$ or $Y \subset W$.

Comment: You don't need to go to this level of detail: if you assume the $\Rightarrow$ direction holds, then $W^\Omega\subset Y^\Omega \implies (Y^\Omega)^\Omega\subset (W^\Omega)^\Omega$, i.e. $Y\subset W$.